# How to import Profile2 users with taxonomy terms using Feeds?

Tags: migrations, users, taxonomy-terms, feeds

I need to migrate a user-database into a new drupal system that uses Profile2 user profiles. The Drupal user profile contains fields like "gender", which are Term references (field type). This reference points to a Vocabulary, in which the genders are stored. Now I have a CSV file containing all users from the old database, and a Feeds importer. The importer is setup straight forward and all "value"-fields (surname, lastname, etc.) are working, but the term reference fields are not filled. How do I setup the importer correctly?

I tried to use the gender name (male/female) and even tried the respective term-IDs (`tid`). The first try results in an error message (wrong input format something), the second one does not produce error outputs but leaves the term reference fields blank as well. I also tried the "Entity Field Query finder" tamper plugin, but without success.

Am I missing something? Or is this import to complex for the Feeds plugin?

Answer (score 1):

In the feeds reference importer>mapping click the button under "Search taxonomy terms by: Term name" on the term reference mapping you're wishing to search and click the check box, then save.

Comment: There is no such a thing (http://pbrd.co/1AMyxWs). In the screen, "land" is the Term reference field. Am I missing a module?

Comment: You're doing it right. Not sure which vocabulary it's connected to right now. It asks for you to select the category when you create the term reference in the user manage fields tab while you're creating the filed. If this is not done or pointing to an empty category you'll need to create a vocabulary for the "land" term reference with at least one term for it to show up there. Once it's connected then you can import from your list.  This is the only way I have seen the term reference not show up in mapping.

Comment: The term reference field points to a vocabulary, which is filles with 5 different entries ... :/